# How do I view list of commit messages between two branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

There is a repository located at:

http://hg.tryton.org/trytond

How do I view list of changes (as commits and messages) between branches 2.8 and 3.0?

I tried

```
$ hg log -r "2.8:3.0" --template '{node|short} {desc|strip|firstline}\n' 
e1e5cf5700d0 Increase version number
faa26bc2e908 Added tag 2.8.12 for changeset a81a53304344
a81a53304344 Prepare release 2.8.12
b57e24462eb1 Increase version number
```

But it lists not all changes made between 2.8 and 3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
hg log -r "(ancestors(2.8) or ancestors(3.0)) and not (ancestors(2.8) and ancestors(3.0))"
```

Comment: @omeinusch - it's obvious! "All revisions in both branches, starting from (but without) common ancestor"

Comment: Revset is shitty unreadable scrap (while it's *technically* correct). Same revset with the same logic in more compact form `-r "(ancestors(2.8) - ancestors(3.0)) + (ancestors(3.0) - ancestors(2.8))"`

Comment: My revset isn't ideal too, because greatest common ancestor of two changesets is just `ancestor(3.0,2.8)`

Answer (score 0):

Log of changes between *branches*?! **How** you'll imagine this? Branches are independent (mutable) trees with (possible) common ancestor in the past

Revset with ":" range produced, as expected

> All changesets with revision numbers between x and y, both inclusive.

```
hg glog -r "2.8:3.0" -T "{branch} {rev} {tags}\n{node|short} {desc|strip|firstline}\n\n"
o  2.8 4801
|  e1e5cf5700d0 Increase version number
|
o  2.8 4800
|  faa26bc2e908 Added tag 2.8.12 for changeset a81a53304344
|
o  2.8 4799 2.8.12
|  a81a53304344 Prepare release 2.8.12
|
| o  3.0 4798
| |  b57e24462eb1 Increase version number
| |
```

When you use branch-name as revision-id, branch's tip used as node, and *before* any commits into any of affected by revset branches, you'll get only this result

While I can't find any reasonable backend in you query, I have to ask "Which was your **real business-task?**"

**Add-on**

Log with hardcoded revset for "revisions between two last tags in branches 2.8 and 3.0" will be

`hg log -r "last(tag('re:^2.8')):last(tag('re:^3.0'))"`

and revset can be easy converted into the parametrized `[revsetalias]` like

`cbt($1, $2) = last(tag('re:^$1')):last(tag('re:^$2'))`

and log can be shortened to

`hg log -r "cbt(2.8, 3.0)"`

```
2.8 4799 2.8.12
a81a53304344 Prepare release 2.8.12

3.0 4798
b57e24462eb1 Increase version number

3.0 4797
a1dc5578784d Added tag 3.0.8 for changeset ff943130c7c4

3.0 4796 3.0.8
ff943130c7c4 Prepare release 3.0.8
```

and used for any pair of branches

Comment: real business-task is to find what has changed between 2.8 and 3.0 versions. reading commit messages instead of reading code would be great!

Comment: @MariusGrigaitis - you have no 2.8|3.0 **versions**, you have 2.8.X and 3.0.X versions (tags) in *diverged history* (see glog). Latest release (tag) in 3.0 was 3.0.8 (4796), latest release in 2.8 - 2.8.12 (4799), see `hg tags`. Both tags are not heads (and never will|can be heads of branches), chronological log *between tags* seems more logical, but anyway **will not** have a lot more changesets, than your attempt

Comment: So how about differences between 2.8.12:3.0.8?

Comment: @MariusGrigaitis - see may add-on in answer